# Runnable.Run / StartCoroutine calles to Watson services from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, coroutine

In my `ExampleStreaming.cs` script, once the user utterance is recognized as `final`, I send it to both the `Watson Assistant` service and the `Tone Analyzer`. Because I am keeping the scripts for each service separate as they are, I have to make calls within each script to access the other service. You can see the call I make to the `Tone Analyzer` below (the `.SendToneAnalysis` method):

```
private void OnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    blah blah blah . . .

    /// Only send the recognized speech utterance to the
    /// Assistant once we know the user has stopped talking.
    if (res.final)
    {
        string _conversationString = alt.transcript;
        Runnable.Run( StopRecording(1f) ); // Stop the microphone from listening.

    /// Message.
    Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["text"] = _conversationString
    };
    MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest()
    {
        Input = input,
        Context = _Context
    };

    _exampleAssistantV1_script.SendMessageAssistant(messageRequest);
    _exampleToneAnalyzer.SendToneAnalysis(_conversationString);

    . . .
```

In my `ExampleToneAnalyzer.cs` script, I make a simple call to the event-handling methods that are meant to contact the service and also handle success & failure:

```
public void SendToneAnalysis(string conversationString)
{
    _service.GetToneAnalyze(OnGetToneAnalyze, OnFail, conversationString);
}
```

These calls are typically made using `StartCoroutines`, particularly in the Watson Unity SDK that there is a specialized `Runnable.Run` which is essentially a helper class for running co-routines without having to inherit from `MonoBehavior`.

My question is whether my simple method call to the service might be problematic in certain situations or perhaps just wrong or bad programming, or whether it is perfectly OK to go for that method instead of something like the following:

```
public void SendToneAnalysis(string conversationString)
{
    Runnable.Run( SendAssistantToneAnalysis(conversationString) );
}

private IEnumerator SendAssistantToneAnalysis(string conversationString)
{
    if ( !_service.GetToneAnalyze(OnGetToneAnalyze, OnFail, conversationString) )
    {
        Log.Debug("ExampleToneAnalyzer.SendAssistantToneAnalysis()", "Failed to analyze!");
    }

    while (!_UserUtteranceToneTested)
        yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make any of the service calls from within a coroutine. Only authentication using `iamApikey` should be done using a coroutine

```
IEnumerator TokenExample()
{
    //  Create IAM token options and supply the apikey. IamUrl is the URL used to get the 
    //  authorization token using the IamApiKey. It defaults to https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token
    TokenOptions iamTokenOptions = new TokenOptions()
    {
        IamApiKey = "<iam-api-key>",
        IamUrl = "<iam-url>"
    };

    //  Create credentials using the IAM token options
    _credentials = new Credentials(iamTokenOptions, "<service-url>");
    while (!_credentials.HasIamTokenData())
        yield return null;

    _assistant = new Assistant(_credentials);
    _assistant.VersionDate = "2018-02-16";
    _assistant.ListWorkspaces(OnListWorkspaces, OnFail);
}
```

The examples are only meant to show how to invoke the service call. The only reason the code is invoked from a coroutine is so we can wait for the response of one service call before running another service call (i.e. so we don't try to update or delete a workspace before the workspace is created).

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem.
Runnable.Run() eventually calls StartCoroutine() as the follow.

```
    public Routine(IEnumerator a_enumerator)
    {
        _enumerator = a_enumerator;
        Runnable.Instance.StartCoroutine(this);
        Stop = false;
        ID = Runnable.Instance._nextRoutineId++;

        Runnable.Instance._routines[ID] = this;
    #if ENABLE_RUNNABLE_DEBUGGING
        Log.Debug("Runnable.Routine()", "Coroutine {0} started.", ID ); 
    #endif
    }
```

Please refer to https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/master/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs

And the coroutine can be called from any gameobject, if it is active.

Comment: Thank you :) Do you mean "no problem" if I use a simple method call that only has `_service.GetToneAnalyze(OnGetToneAnalyze, OnFail, conversationString)` inside? So, I don't need to use the `Runnable` way of doing this? Or do you mean I must use `Runnable` for such calls?

Comment: If you need to wait for something like "_UserUtteranceToneTested", you need to use Runnable, but if not, you don't need to use that.

Comment: Additionally, if `_service.GetToneAnalyze(OnGetToneAnalyze, OnFail, conversationString)` you said means this(https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/unity-sdk/docs/v2.0.0/html/5E210DC9.htm), you don't need to use the Runnable or coroutine.